# How to get the factorial using rep statement in r?

Tags: r, factorial, rep

I want to get the factorial function with rep statement.

I try!! But failed!!

```
   fact <- function(n){
      for (i in 0:n){
        while(i<n){
          rep{n*fact(n-1) if(i ==n) break}
       }
    }
```

thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: Don't put code in an image - put it in the actual question. No one is going to want to manually transcribe your image if they want to help.

Comment: oh... ok. I wirte the code.

Comment: `rep` is used to repeat values of a vector, did you maybe mean `replicate`?

Comment: yes, right rep means replicate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant `replicate`, not `rep` this would be a solution:

```
fact <- function(N){
  n <- N
  f <- 1
  replicate(n, {
    f <<- f*n
    n <<- n-1
    f
  })[N]
}
```

Of course only use this as an exercise, because it is way slower than the build in `factorial` function.

If you're into functional programming you could use the following lambda-based solution:

```
N <- 10

factorial_generator <- function(){
  fac <- 1
  n <- 0
  function(){
    n <<- n+1
    fac <<- fac * n
    return(fac)
  }
}

my_factorial <- factorial_generator()

replicate(N, my_factorial())[N]
```